# Analytics pageview/ event code is result in stats

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to get statistics about sign ups on my website.

The analytics code is in the header:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=...."></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', '....');
    </script>
```

Then I have a form and sending it (with a page reload, not ajax) and in the success snippet in razor I placed the ga code:

```
@if (success)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ga('send', 'event', 'Supplier sign up', 'click', '/signup/success');
    </script>
    <p>success message</p>
}
```

The success message appears and I can see the script in the page inspect but I don't get any stats in Google Analytics.

Am I missing something? In the past (a few years ago) I was using a similar code and it worked. Has anything changed recently? Do I need to enable something in the Analytics or my code is wrong?

I am following the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Answer (score 1):

The implementation method for your GA is through gtag.s, not GTM or analytics.js.

Thus you need to modify your success to:

```
@if (success)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
       gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Supplier sign up', 'event_label': '/signup/success'});
    </script>
    <p>success message</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed two GA libraries. You use `gtag.js` for page view, so you need to use `gtag.js` (not `analytics.js`) for events.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events

Comment: Well, the tracking code above is the only one I have avaiable to copy and paste in my Analytics. I have no GTM account though and I had never installed it. Yet I am getting stats from my site in GA. I am not sure I should to setup up anything in GTM in this case for gtag() to work?

Comment: @nickornotto It's because of `gtag.js` is a new, preferable library. You don't need GTM. Just change line in your code for event from `ga('send', 'event', 'Supplier sign up', 'click', '/signup/success');` to `gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Supplier sign up', 'event_label': '/signup/success'});`.